# Angular2 - Routing for file download

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an **Angular2** application and I'm having some troubles with file downloads:

The application runs locally on my machine:

```
http://localhost:4200
```

All files are located under:

```
myapp/src/assets
```

An example of The file url rendered in the page is:

```
http://localhost:4200/assets/OffertFile/2234/Offerta%20iniziale.xlsx
```

This is how I generate the links in html component:

```
<a href="{{v.excel_Path}}/{{v.excel_FileName}}" download target="_self">
    <i class="fa fa-download fa-2x text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

If I try to download the file, I get a file containing the **index.html** page file content and not the properly file itself.

I think Its a routing problem.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: How do you generate variable 'v' in your controller ?

Comment: I use a service, the path is properly composet, it render: "http://localhost:4200/assets/OffertFile/2234/Offerta%20iniziale.xlsx" , like I have written in the post...

Comment: I'm facing the same problema. Have you come up with a solution for this?

Comment: Hi Bruno, you have to use [routerLink] tag instead of href

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be caused by two reasons:

1. Check if the referenced file actually exists in the file system on your web server.
2. Case sensitivity - check if the file name in the link has exactly the same case (upper, or lower, or combined) as the file name in the file system.